# spring .save cannot be referenced

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple service file in spring, I am completely beginner in Java and therefore do not understand why I am getting an error message while on a given example it works fine.

Here's an error message:

> Error:(24, 35) java: non-static method save(S) cannot be referenced
>   from a static context

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    protected static UserEntryRepository userEntryRepository;

    public static List<UserEntry> findAll() {
        return userEntryRepository.findAll();
    }

    public static UserEntry save(UserEntry entry) {
        return UserEntryRepository.save(entry);
    }
}
```

It seems there is a problem with .save but I do not understand why, if any more code is required please let me know ;)

Comment: remove `static`from your methods and properties

Comment: Also learn the basics of Java befor starting with spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove `static` from the autowired field and replace `UserEntryRepository.save(entry);` with `userEntryRepository.save(entry);`

Comment: works fine such a stupid mistake

Comment: It took me 5 minutes to notice the change in `UserEntryRepository.save(entry);` and `userEntryRepository.save(entry);` just in in case you face it too its the upper case and lower case of class '**U**serEntryRepository'